# 500 Internal Error for PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am new to php codeigniter, I need upload files like 100 mb size. So from the internet I found the way to edit my php.ini file. BUT in codeigniter the php.ini file not working for sub folders. I need to use it everywhere, so I wrote the super user access to .htaccess file, but I am getting 500 Inter server error.

`RewriteEngine on
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
      suPHP_ConfigPath /home/edukeepi/public_html/php.ini`

> Why I am getting this error?

Comment: What does it say in your error logs?

Comment: Check if you have loaded `mod_suphp.c` apache module.

Comment: How can I? can you a code sample as above code or can you edit my code? @Tpojka

Answer (score 0):

Please try to upload in ./resources/ folder. As in your .htaccess you are allowing 'resources' folder to write file (i.e. upload)